# Header <h1> in Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have my Bootstrap tabs flush with my page header (mock shown below), but having the header taller than the other tabs causes everything to break. How can I do this?

[image: Mock]

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li><h1>Header</h1></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li class="pull-right"><button id="new-thing" class="btn btn-primary">New</button></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the font size and margin spacing I want. Now I just need the tabs flush with the bottom border.
http://jsfiddle.net/bK4a4/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete margin

```
li h1 { margin: 0}
```

*After Edit* Options

- add `margin-top` to other elements. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96Uru)
- add `line-height` to h1 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y6FV)

Comment: This works, but to be more specific it is the top and bottom margins that need to be 0. Left and right margins are fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/bK4a4/2/

Comment: I agreed, but with `margin: 0 10px;` looks mouch better.

Comment: I've updated my post. I'm interested in more margin and a larger font size. Sorry I wasn't more clear. Check linked fiddle.

Comment: @savinger so add `margin-top:` to other elements http://jsfiddle.net/96Uru/ or add `line-height` to h1 http://jsfiddle.net/2y6FV/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.nav-tabs h1 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 5px !important;
}
```

You can change the font size, weight and margins to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

in your html , make a class for the header

```
<li><h1 class="header">Header</h1><li>
```

and in your csss

```
html, body {
    padding: 1em;
}

.header {
margin:0; 
padding:0;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle to check it out : [jsFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bK4a4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li><div style=" font-size:25px">Header&nbsp  </div></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
<li class="pull-right"><button id="new-thing" class="btn btn-primary">New</button></li></ul>
```

where you use inline css to specify the font size and margin